# Why is color setting to UIDatePicker not activated until date is chosen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, colors, uidatepicker

I am able to change the color of the text and the background color but the changes are only visible after I pick a date and tap the go button. Is there a way that the color changes can be made effective as soon as the app launches. Here is a video of the issue occurring... https://www.youtube.com/embed/GlA0LIYC1VU

Here is my code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var dateWheel: UIDatePicker!


@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

    dateWheel.backgroundColor = .blue
    dateWheel.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")

    let dateStringFormatter = DateFormatter()


    dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sss"
    dateStringFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to move the `dateWheel.backgroundColor = .blue
    dateWheel.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")`

inside of `viewDidLoad`

After that issue was resolved.

Reddit helped me with this answer u/pkoddity